# Class Def Not found in Java App for Tridion

Tags: content-delivery, taxonomy

I have a standalone Java Web Application where I am trying to fetch the Claimstore key value pair inside a Servlet. While trying to fetch the triggers, I am getting a ClassDefNotFoundError at "com.tridion.taxonomies.formatters.TaxonomyFormatter".

I am not able to find the jar file for the above class. Please provide the jar file name which I can include to remove the exception.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is part of `cd_broker.jar`. this might be missing in your lib folder